# are scipys solver method interior-point and revised-simplex really slow?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming, solver, scipy-optimize

I'm working on some LP and I'm testing the scipy solvers
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-interior-point.html
and
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-revised_simplex.html

I know that there are the newer highs methods
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-highs.html#optimize-linprog-highs

but I want to use the old ones as I want to test a "normal" simplex implementation...

I'm solving a 200x200 Problem with a constraint matrix of 400,40000

the revised simplex method took 16 minutes to solve...IP took about 10 minutes.
this is unbelievable slow?!
Am I doing something wrong or are those old methods really so bad?

If someone knows a good running python implementation of the simplex, IP or dual simplex feel free to share.. I want to see how the perform in comparison to scipy

cheers

Comment: 1) Interior-point is not Simplex 2) I don't see a reason to pick non-HIGHS based solvers when Simplex is needed (e.g. because one needs a basic feasible solution). 3) It's unclear what a *normal* simplex implementation is. Practioners in Operations-Research always use the *best performing* codes which fulfill their use-cases and the only solver-backend *somewhat approaching state of the art* within scipy is Highs (in Simplex-world).  4) A `200x200 problem` as description is rather vague and sounds dense which real solvers are not tuned for as real-world instances are usually sparse.

Comment: Leaving scipy for any lib supporting CoinOR Clp as solver will probably beat all those (including Highs, where the difference might be smaller) easily. E.g. python-mip, pulp or pyomo. See also [these benchmarks](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpsimp.html) which show some free solvers (among many commercial ones). *State of the art* as mentioned earlier is also often limited to *free solvers* as commercials are often out of reach (less for LPs, more for MIPs). The benchmark might also indicate, that raw performance is not everything as numerical-stability / memory-usage might also matter.

Comment: @sascha thanks for your fast response!  The problem with HIGHS is that I don't really understand how the parallel computation of the revised simplex method works and the papers are quite difficult to understand....

Unfortunately I couldn't use CoinOr, Pulp or Pyomo as they don't allow a specific algorithm selection and I want to compare specific algorithms....

Comment: @sascha which memory profiler would you recommend for python? atm I'm using https://pypi.org/project/psutil/

Comment: 1)I would argue, that you won't be able to understand any of the *well performing solvers* without months of intensive work. At least if pursueing being able to *hack on it*. This is a highly optimized domain at the intersection of computer science and math. Clp has ~200k lines of (C++) code. 2)Clp allows selecting primal simplex, dual simplex, sifting and co.Not sure what more you need.I really wonder what you are trying to do (+ what insights you try to gain).3)I can't recommend a memory-profiler, but also: i'm sceptic about gaining insights. Memory depends on sparsity structure=!your! data

Comment: @sascha 1) it might be difficult to understand the solvers themselves but I mean the theory behind them. If solved in parallel the revised simplex method differs a lot from the "classic" one or am I wrong?

2)  do you have the link to a tutorial or documentation on how to select different algorithms in clp using python? I haven't found anything about that online.... this is why I went for scipy...
I'm working on my thesis and should compare different algorithms..

Comment: None of those (good)solvers follow the textbook descr you learned at your university (*there is no tableau*). The only book i'm aware of touching the theory vs. practice aspect is [Computational Techniques of the Simplex Method](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781402073328). Python-MIP let's you chose primal, dual and barrier/imp [here](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes.html#lp-method). Pyomo / pulp should be able to pass all options such that the ones from CoinOR Clp can be used. Consider the documentation of Clp then (might be somewhat hidden within some doxygen classes).

Comment: Note that if you're using `highs-ds` as the optimization method, you're not using the parallel solver in HiGHS. Indeed, the parallel one isn't even available through the high-level SciPy API at the moment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/17250